# How to use Simlink PID tools to implement a controller in matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink, pid-controller

I was wondering if it is possible to use simlink's PID architecture in matlab to actually control hardware - rather than modelling it.

I have been playing around a little with the PID tuning in matlab - and have worked out the correct gains for my system (or at least good enough).

Now I want to implement the actual control loop in matlab using the real hardware.  In this case I am tying to stabilise a laser using a measurement from a wavemeter - although from the point of view of matlab essentially I have two functions - one which returns the current wavelength, and another which alters the wavelength with an input from 0-100.

How do I get the fancy PID objects to work in a loop where for example I input data each loop, and get the required output to stabilise things given my gains - or should I just hardcode the equations in?

I have tried looking through some of the simlink examples - but there doesn't seem to me much actual implementation - mostly just modelling.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB (without Simulink, or with Simulink in purely a simulation mode) is not a real-time environment.  Trying to use it to control hardware in real-time won't work unless you have very slow sample rates.

If you do have slow sample rates, then you'd connect to your hardware to MATLAB using device drivers such as those in the [Data Acquisition Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/daq.html)

You haven't found any info on real-time implementation in the Simulink documentation because from Simulink the mechanism for real-time implementation is via [Simulink Coder](https://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink-coder.html).  You would need to use it in conjunction with a real-time environment such as [Simulink Desktop Real-Time](https://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink-desktop-real-time.html) (if your sample rates are relatively slow), [Simulink Real-Time](https://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink-real-time.html), or one of many other 3rd party real-time form factors.

Comment: Thanks... that was what I was coming to the conclusion of...  Actually our sample rate is pretty slow - we are restricted with the input from our wavemeter - since we didn't pay for the voltage output we only have usb aquisition rates (so probably something around kHz at best - or rather as quick as matlab can talk to them).  For this reason I haven't done much with our output daq....

Comment: I guess it is a pity though... seems that even Simulink Desktop Real-Time isn't so easy to implement... if I'm right it seems like you need a separate computer apart from the development computer.  Presumably to ensure that you have enough resources or something to be somewhat 'realtime'....  but would be cool if it was possible to try things out easily in the matlab environment beforehand.

Comment: With Simulink Desktop Real-Time you use one computer - with both your development tools (that is MATLAB, SImulink,etc.) on it, and all your DAQ hardware connected to it.  It is pretty easy to use.  With Simulink Real-Time you have two computers - one with the development environment and one as the deployment computer.

Comment: Ok... Maybe I'll take another look...I must have misread it - it seems like I couldn't find the Desktop version...  Maybe I need to install a newer version - or make sure of the licence...Thanks for the help though.. JP